# Listing network interfaces in Haskell

Tags: networking, haskell, ip

How can I list all network interfaces from Haskell?  All `getHost*` functions from `Network.BSD`, that I've tried, gave me only the `localhost` entry.

Comment: @qubital you should set your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library [`Network.Info`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network-info/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Network-Info.html) provides a `getNetworkInterfaces` function that should work for you.